# ActiveRecord multiple joins through association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

My customer model has many videos and videos has many video activities.

I want to join on video activities to limit based off videos that belong to a customer who has a specific email domain.

This code will give me all the video activities belonging to customer with id 52, but since videos don't have customer email, I need to join customer onto video and then do a .where.

```
VideoActivity.joins(:video).where(videos: {customer_id: 52})
```

How is this done? Doing `VideoActivity.joins(:video).joins(:customer)` gives me an error saying VideoActivity doesn't have a customer associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VideoActiviy has no relation with customer, you need to say that the customer is related to the video, then it's easier to use active record's [`#merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) that doing a hash `where`

```
VideoActivity.joins(video: :customer).merge(Customer.where('some condition'))
```

If you have a scope in videos you could use that too, here's an example

```
VideoActivity.joins(video: :customer).merge(Customer.some_scope)
```

**PS:**

a scope could be

```
# customer model
scope :email_ends_with, ->(string) { where('email ilike ?', "%#{string}") }
```

Then use it

```
VideoActivity.joins(video: :customer).merge(Customer.email_ends_with('gmail.com'))
```

Comment: I need to reference email on the customer model, not customer ID on the video model though. that's where my issue is.

Comment: I need to filter by video activities that belong to a video that belong to a customer who has an email ilike '%@gmail.com' for example.

Comment: like `VideoActivity.joins(video: :customer).merge(Customer.where(email: 'some email'))` ?

Comment: well you can place any query that returns customers inside the merge, so you could do `merge(Customer.where("email like '%@gmail.com'")`

Comment: @parameter, added a scope example

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this and all end up at about the same place, but using an explicit where statement will easily accomplish this goal.

```
   VideoActivity.joins(:video).where("videos.customer_id = ?", 52)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write plain sql to fetch records

```
activities = VideoActivity.joins('INNER JOIN videos ON video_activities.video_id = videos.id INNER JOIN customers ON videos.customer_id = customers.id')
activities.where('customers.email = ?', customer_email)
```